# Short story: limited life spans, arm tattoos, gang of kids on minibikes

Tags: story-identification, dystopia, anthology-book

This is from an dystopian anthology I read in the early 1970's.

The world is run-down and brutal, reminiscent of Soylent Green / Make Room Make Room. Everyone has a tattoo on their arm indicating their birth date. You can earn a reward (I think: extending your own life) by killing someone and bringing their arm / tattoo to the authorities.

An old man meets a young boy who is in a theft-and-killing gang (they all ride minibikes) and tries to teach the boy about a better way to live. The old man has a different colored tattoo, much more valuable than the normal.  The story ends where the old man intentionally leaves a knife on a table (while cooking) and turns his back to the boy, leaving unresolved whether the boy believed and befriended the old man, or killed him for his tattoo / reward.

Comment: Apart from the minibikes the following question/answer seems very similar. But, I would think you would have remembered the piano. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71812/seeking-sf-short-story-from-late-1970s-early-1980s-about-dystopian-future-with-a

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @beichst that is indeed the story.

Ref: this question and answer: [Seeking SF Short Story from late 1970s/early 1980s about dystopian future with an old man playing a piano](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71812/seeking-sf-short-story-from-late-1970s-early-1980s-about-dystopian-future-with-a)